# AWS Lambda function for collecting FSX information

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to collect FSX capacity via lambda function using Python3.9

```
fsx_connection = boto3.client('fsx', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,aws_session_token = SESSION_TOKEN, region_name="eu-west-1")
```

How can I collect the fsx storage capacity with fsx_connection components?

Thanks in advance;

Comment: Documentation: [FSx — Boto3 Docs documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/fsx.html) What have you tried? What specific issue are you having?

Comment: I am trying to display in cloudwatch a dashboard with FSX data such as: FSX capacity, FSX usage. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Monitoring with Amazon CloudWatch - Amazon FSx for Windows File Server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/monitoring-cloudwatch.html), the only metrics available for Amazon CloudWatch are:

- DataReadBytes
- DataWriteBytes
- DataReadOperations
- DataWriteOperations
- MetadataOperations
- **FreeStorageCapacity:** The amount of available storage capacity (in bytes)

Comment: I am trying to display FreeStorageCapacity dat
a via Grafana.
I have connected my cloudwatch to Grafana but for some reason the FreeStorageCapacity metrics is not supported. So I am trying to pull the data using Lambda

Comment: An AWS Lambda function should be able to retrieve the data from Amazon CloudWatch Metrics. It's a bit fiddly to get the parameters right -- try it via the AWS CLI first. Then, once you have the right data being returned, code it into the Lambda function.

Comment: I will try using AWS CLI,
Thanks for your help